# Is that possible change device settings only for my application?

Tags: ios, iphone

My application interface is too dark.(Background color dar blue etc..) so, I want to change iOS devices settings automatically. (increase light level automatically when my application starting.) Is that possible ?

Comment: Try [UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.m file, look for, `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method, and write this any where before `return`call.

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
```

From document,

> 0 .. 1.0, where 1.0 is maximum brightness. Only supported by main screen.

P.S. This change you can only able to see on a real device.